# UIToolBar buttons don't work over UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a `UITableView` inside the `ViewController`, on top of it there is a `UIToolbar`.

[image]

A button image is placed inside the **Toolbar**, as shown in the image. What is weird is that when I click that button nothing happens, it seems it's behind the **TableView**. I've tried sending back the **TableView**, like this:

`view.sendSubviewToBack(tableView)`

Simulated output:

[image]

But it did not work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: i am not sure but you  can try bringSubviewToFront as a toolbar

Comment: @AnilPrasad did not work

Comment: your order of controllers is wrong. It should be TableView and then Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your toolbar is under tableview

Just change the order of toolbar

[image]

Comment: I mean in the picture,from top to buttom.You picture is `toobar`,then `tableview`.My picture is 'tableview',then `toobar`